# Web app(python) for Streaming and downloading music preview clip

Tags: python-2.7

I want to build a web app in python which streams **preview music clip** from "7digital" and **downloads** them. How can i achieve it ?

Comment: [Please Read How to Ask on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are probably having issues with the downloading part, the rest seems straightforward, which is web development (but if you need a simple way to make webapps in Python, I recommend that you look into Python Flask). I'll show you how the downloading part could be done with this example:

```
https://us.7digital.com/artist/various-artists/release/beauty-and-the-beast-original-motion-picture-soundtrackdeluxe-edition-6256194
```

If you do a GET request on this page to get the HTML code (you can also see the page code on Chrome if you Right-Click > View page source
-- or better, you can find the music player and Right-Click > Inspect), you will see an HTML element that looks like this:

```
<audio id="jp_audio_0" preload="metadata" src="https://us.7digital.com/stream/release/6256194/track/61861397/mp3" ...
```

If you go to this src link (https://us.7digital.com/stream/release/6256194/track/61861397/mp3), you will see that this is the source location of the streaming music.

Now, for downloading the mp3, use urllib's urlretrieve:

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve("https://us.7digital.com/stream/release/6256194/track/61861397/mp3", "mp3.mp3")
```

This will save the mp3 to your working directory.

-- EDIT AFTER READING COMMENT --

Got it. It sounds like a cool project. I noticed that they have an API for this kind of thing: http://docs.7digital.com . I used "7digital.com" as my API key since this is what the site uses and had no problems, but they probably want you to request one.

STEP 1 (gather tag names): We can use the API to get the list of all category names (there are 470 of them listed, 10 per page):

```
http://api.7digital.com/1.2/tag?oauth_consumer_key=API_KEY&country=US&page=1
http://api.7digital.com/1.2/tag?oauth_consumer_key=API_KEY&country=US&page=2
http://api.7digital.com/1.2/tag?oauth_consumer_key=API_KEY&country=US&page=3

...

http://api.7digital.com/1.2/tag?oauth_consumer_key=API_KEY&country=US&page=47
```

STEP 2 (gather song names by tag): We need to get a list of songs for each category, so you can use something like this:

```
http://api.7digital.com/1.2/release/bytag/top?tags=pop&page=1&pageSize=10&oauth_consumer_key=API_KEY&country=US&usageTypes=download,subscriptionstreaming,adsupportedstreaming
```

You can modify the pageSize from 10 to something higher like 100 to get more results (or just modify the page= number). You can modify the country from US to GB or other countries, and you will of course need to modify the tag from tags=pop to whichever category you are using for each search.

STEP 3 (download a sample for each song): Now you have a list of top tracks for each category- we will need to convert that into sample song downloads. I couldn't quickly figure out how they came up with the embedded music URLs that we need to use for the downloads, but somehow, we need to come up with two numbers for each URL:

```
https://us.7digital.com/stream/release/NUM1/track/NUM2/mp3
```

The URLs of the samples might be shown as links in the API responses. Otherwise, from the format of the URL, the first number appears to be the "release" number and the second the "track" number. You will want to use the method above with urllib to get those.

Comment: Thanks Joe, it was a great help to me. But I was kind of seeking a code that extracts "all" the links for the mp3 preview clip and then saves them.I want to save around million of preview files from 7digital to train my ML code, and it would be very cumbersome for me to do one by one.Hence, I wanted something that will download around 10,000 preview clips per class, classified according to "Genre", "Rock", "Electronic", "Artist" etc; with their actual names.

Comment: No problem, Gaurav. I'm really glad it was helpful. I added an edit to help you in that direction.